# beautifulsoup always returns NoneType

Tags: beautifulsoup

I seem to have a problem with beautifulsoup, who never returns anything no matter what I search for. Example:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
url="http://www.google.com"

html=urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
print type(html)
soup= BeautifulSoup(html)
soup.find_all('div')
```

returns:

```
C:\Users\Alexis\Desktop>ipython scrape.py
<type 'str'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\Alexis\Desktop\scrape.py in <module>()
      7 print type(html)
      8 soup= BeautifulSoup(html)
----> 9 soup.find_all('div')
     10
     11

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I've tried upgrading to the latest version. No change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your import line to this to use BeautifulSoup4:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Change the last line of your program to this to print out the `div`s:

```
for div in soup.find_all('div'):
    print('here comes another div')
    print(div)
```

Comment: same. I get 'Nonetype' object is not callable at the setup of the loop. It seems I cannot use find_all, or any beautifulsoup method, because soup does not seem to be recognized as a beautifulsoup object.

Comment: Are you using BeautifulSoup 3? I think you should use BeautifulSoup 4 - my import line is like this: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Comment: you are correct, adding 'from bs4' before my import solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, glad to hear it.